# mac qt app runs from Qt Creator but crashes if macqtdeploy is used

Tags: macos, qt, macdeployqt

I have a Qt app that for a long time I have successfully built on the Mac inside Qt Creator, then distributed by using macdeployqt then creating a .dmg file. That was on a late-2014 Mac Mini using Qt 5.15.1.

I recently upgraded to a new Mac Mini 2023 using an M2 processor. Since then I have found that the app can still be built and run successfully in Qt Creator (12.0.1), but when I build it on the command line and use macdeployqt, that version crashes in a thread-related function.

**Update: see the end of this post and the notes for a fix that seems to work.**

I have tried using Qt 5.15.1 and 5.15.2 and the results are the same (yes, I have tried Qt 6: see below). Here is the relevant part of the crash report:

```
Process:               CartoTypeMaps [14478]
Path:                  /Volumes/VOLUME/CartoTypeMaps.app/Contents/MacOS/CartoTypeMaps
Identifier:            com.yourcompany.CartoTypeMaps
Version:               ???
Code Type:             X86-64 (Translated)
Parent Process:        launchd [1]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2023-12-28 09:50:05.1807 +0000
OS Version:            macOS 13.5 (22G74)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        E937E16C-6079-DC90-55E4-74D065DDB839


Time Awake Since Boot: 5300 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 6 Abort trap: 6
Terminating Process:   CartoTypeMaps [14478]

Application Specific Information:
abort() called


Thread 0 Crashed::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   ???                                 0x7ff89a48a9a8 ???
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff80a843202 __pthread_kill + 10
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff80a87aee6 pthread_kill + 263
3   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x7ff80a7a1b45 abort + 123
4   libc++abi.dylib                     0x7ff80a835282 abort_message + 241
5   libc++abi.dylib                     0x7ff80a8273e1 demangling_terminate_handler() + 241
6   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x7ff80a4fba7f _objc_terminate() + 104
7   libc++abi.dylib                     0x7ff80a8346db std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 6
8   libc++abi.dylib                     0x7ff80a836fa7 __cxxabiv1::failed_throw(__cxxabiv1::__cxa_exception*) + 27
9   libc++abi.dylib                     0x7ff80a836f6e __cxa_throw + 116
10  CartoTypeMaps                          0x103068463 CartoTypeCore::CVectorTileServer::CVectorTileServer(CartoTypeCore::Framework&, unsigned long, unsigned long) + 1525
```

I have now tried using the latest Qt, version 6.6.1, and the problem is almost the same. The crash is still in a thread-related function. Here is the crash report for the 6.6.1 build:

```
Process:               CartoTypeMaps [20293]
Path:                  /Volumes/VOLUME/CartoTypeMaps.app/Contents/MacOS/CartoTypeMaps
Identifier:            com.yourcompany.CartoTypeMaps
Version:               ???
Code Type:             ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd [1]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2023-12-28 10:22:19.6461 +0000
OS Version:            macOS 13.5 (22G74)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        E937E16C-6079-DC90-55E4-74D065DDB839


Time Awake Since Boot: 7200 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        47

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 6 Abort trap: 6
Terminating Process:   CartoTypeMaps [20293]

Application Specific Information:
abort() called


Thread 0::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1aa127750 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1aa164574 _pthread_cond_wait + 1232
2   libc++.1.dylib                         0x1aa08cef0 std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 28
3   QtCore                                 0x1033af1b4 QSemaphore::acquire(int) + 80
4   QtGui                                  0x101b022dc 0x1016a0000 + 4596444
5   QtGui                                  0x101ae452c 0x1016a0000 + 4474156
6   QtGui                                  0x1017e7800 0x1016a0000 + 1341440
7   QtGui                                  0x10180d358 0x1016a0000 + 1495896
8   QtGui                                  0x10180f844 QRasterPaintEngine::fill(QVectorPath const&, QBrush const&) + 1248
```

Note that the crash is exactly same in 6.6.1 for both architectures: ARM-64 and X86-64 (Translated).

I suspect that the app finds the wrong dynamic library when run from the version using macdeployqt, but I don't know what to do about that.

Following advice from Jeremy Friesner in a comment, I tried running the app from a command line to see the abort message and got this result:

```
./CartoTypeMaps.app/Contents/MacOS/CartoTypeMaps
QThreadPipe: Unable to create pipe: Too many open files
QEventDispatcherUNIXPrivate(): Cannot continue without a thread pipe
zsh: abort      ./CartoTypeMaps.app/Contents/MacOS/CartoTypeMaps
```

**I have been able to fix the problem** by increasing the maximum number of open files on my Mac Mini, which arrived with the rather low number of 256.

When running the app from the terminal I used the command `ulimit -n 10240`, which worked, but the `ulimit` command affects only the current process, so that didn't fix the problem for running the app by double-clicking the .dmg file and then double-clicking the app icon inside the opened disk image. To handle the latter problem, after some searching I discovered [this solution](https://developer.apple.com/forums//thread/735798?answerId=762208022#762208022):

```
sudo launchctl limit maxfiles 256 unlimited
sudo launchctl limit maxfiles 128000 524288
```

and both commands are indeed necessary.

Obviously it would be useful to know why so many files are being opened, and I'll have another look at my app; but I don't think it opens more than 40 or 50. It looks as if the limit of 256 is not for an individual app but system-wide.

I would also like to know why everything worked fine when running the app from Qt Creator, but I suspect that it increases the file limit itself for any processes it launches.

Comment: If you run the app from Terminal (eg ./CartoTypeMaps.app/Contents/MacOS/CartoTypeMaps ) you should see an error message printed to stderr by the abort() call just before the app crashes; that should give a clue as to what is going wrong.

Comment: Jeremy, thank you for your kind advice. I have tried that and will add the result to my original question.

Comment: Hmm.  If you run `ulimit -a` in Terminal, what is the limit-value printed for "open files" ?

Comment: Hi Jeremy, trying to fix the maximum number of open files is what I have been doing since getting your advice - thanks again - and again I'll add the notes to my post.

Comment: FWIW here is the function my program calls to make sure it can open as many files as allowable under MacOS:  `void RaiseFileLimitToMaximum()
{        
   struct rlimit rl;
   if (getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, &rl) == 0)
   {
      if (((int)rl.rlim_max) > ((int)rl.rlim_cur))  
      {
         rl.rlim_cur = rl.rlim_max;
         if (setrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, &rl) != 0) perror("setrlimit");
      }
   }  
   else perror("getrlimit");
}`

Comment: I'll add that code to my program.